# Visualising code dependency in Flutter apps

Tags: flutter, uml, visualization

I'm a somewhat grizzled IT veteran (COBOL, Fortran etc ca1975) diving into Flutter via Kodeco's Flutter Apprentice (→Ch 5). But I'm puzzled as well as grizzled. Does Flutter development not need visual tools for the code?  I can't find anything to show what UML calls dependency relationships, e.g. ClassTwo is dependent on ClassOne because it accesses a property or method of ClassOne. Is this not important (e.g. for code maintenance ...)? Any comments?

dcdg / plantUML produces nice but limited class diagrams. dartdoc produces very nice text documentation. Flutter Explorer shows widgets but not other classes.